# iPod app won't delete

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod, facebook

My Facebook Messenger app will not open, and when I click it nothing happens. It will not let me delete the app. My iPod was updating the app for over a whole day and nothing was happening, as I am in Thailand at the moment with very bad Internet. I tried to delete the app so I could reinstall it. However, nothing happens, and now it remains shaded grey and says 'waiting' at the bottom.

Comment: Go to the Facebook Messenger app's page on the app store, then click the `Stop` square to stop the download and remove it from your iPod.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > General > Storage & iCloud Usage > Storage: Manage Storage

Scroll down until you find Facebook Messenger. Touch it. Touch "Delete App."

Once it has been deleted, you can reinstall it.